# c++14 variadic template issue 'is ambiguous'

Tags: c++, c++14

I have such snippet:

```
    template<typename Last>
    bool apply_impl(data_t * d) const
    {
        return this->Last::apply(*this, vs);
    }

    template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
    bool apply_impl(data_t * d) const
    {
        return this->Head::apply(*this, d) && this->template apply_impl<Tail...>(d);
    }
```

Compiler error is:

```
error: call to member function 'apply_impl' is ambiguous
        return this->Head::apply(*this, vs) && this->template apply_impl<Tail...>(vs);
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like there is not necessary for more details, people got what I need :)

Comment: @Barry What's missing?

Comment: @Angew An actual mcve is missing.

Comment: @Barry It's minimal and there's enough in there to quickly identify and solve the problem. Do we really need a copy&paste example even if it's obvious the problem is not in the missing parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this using tag dispatch to mark the end condition:

```
template <class...>
struct TypeList {};

template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
bool apply_impl(data_t * d, TypeList<Head, Tail...> = {}) const
{
    return this->Head::apply(*this, d) && this->apply_impl(d, TypeList<Tail...>{});
}

bool apply_impl(data_t * d, TypleList<>) const
{ return true; }
```

This way, the template version will handle all the template arguments, and the non-template will just provide a terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to resolve this?*

```cpp
template <typename Last>
bool apply_impl(data_t* d) const
{
    return Last::apply(*this, vs);
}

template <typename Head, typename RunnerUp, typename... Tail>
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
bool apply_impl(data_t* d) const
{
    return Head::apply(*this, d) && apply_impl<RunnerUp, Tail...>(d);
    //                                         ~~~~~~~^
}
```

In C++17:

```cpp
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
bool apply_impl(data_t* d) const
{
    return Head::apply(*this, d) && (Tail::apply(*this, d) && ...);
}
```